# Error migrating Django 1.6 to Django 1.10 with python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have an application here that was made using version 1.6 of Django, and I am trying to migrate to version 1.10. 
It turns out I'm going through some problems, and I'm not sure if it's because of differences between versions. When I run 'python manage.py runserver', the following error occurs:

> socialconnections.SocialInfluence.social_auth: (fields.E300) Field
>   defines a relation with model 'default.UserSocialAuth', which is
>   either not installed, or is abstract.

The default.UserSocialAuth class is set to INSTALLED_APPS (social.apps.django_app.default). Has anyone ever gone through something like that and have any idea why this is happening? The code snippet that gives error is as follows:

```
social_auth = models.OneToOneField(
    'default.UserSocialAuth',
    related_name='social_influence')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, upgrading 1.6 to 1.10 in one go is a huge change. You'll find it much easier if you get Django 1.8 working first (it's an LTS so there's no need to upgrade to 1.10 yet). I would also recommend upgrading via Django 1.7, since it will make fixing deprecations easier. Once you've got 1.8 working, then upgrading to 1.10 or jumping straight to 1.11 LTS when it comes out will be straight forward.

Comment: Hi, @Alasdair. This error occurs too in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the @alasdair user's recommendation of gradually upgrading, and the project worked on version 1.7 of Django.